# How to set "value" attribute if the "type" attribute is "number"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a scenario to automate the Display order field which has type attribute is number like type=number and there is no value attribute on it.

```
<td width="150px">
     <div class="ngTableCell text-center" ng-show="ChildDet.SectionID==parentDet.ID">
     <input type="number" min="1" max="2" onkeydown="return false" ng-focus="OrderDetailsFocus(ChildDet)" ng-blur="OrderDetailsChange(parentDet.ID,$index,ChildDet)" ng-disabled="ChildDet.CheckStatus==true ?false:true" ng-model="ChildDet.OrderDetails" style="width:50px" class="ng-valid-min ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-max ng-valid-number">
     <label>&nbsp;</label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
```

Comment: have you tried sendkeys method on input.?

Comment: ya...but its not working... even we cant type value in this input field by manual also..

Answer (score 1):

First, it's important to distinguish between an HTML "attribute" and a JavaScript object "property"...

Attributes are HTML markup that define a certain characteristic of the **element** they are attached to. We use attributes to set the *initial* state of the element.

Properties store the *current* "in-memory" value of a characteristic of an **object**.

Often, there is a 1 to 1 mapping between an attribute and a property (i.e. the `id` attribute value set in the markup will be the same as the `id` property of the object that represents that HTML element). But, when you access an object's properties via JavaScript, the initial value you get comes from the initial value in the HTML, but from there, the JavaScript may change this value in memory.

Just about all HTML form elements can have a `value` attribute. That doesn't mean that it "must" have a `value` statically set in the source code (which is how you would set a default value). The `value` property is where the data is held and is what you access from JavaScript to get the value of the field.

So, in your case, while you are not explicitly initializing the `value` attribute (and thus the `value` property), that doesn't mean the element doesn't have a `value`. It just means that the value will have to come from somewhere else and with form elements, that is typically the data that the user fills in.

Just access the `value` property after the user has had a chance to set it.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  console.log(document.querySelector("input[type=number]").value);
});
```

```html
     <input type="number" min="1" max="2" onkeydown="return false" ng-focus="OrderDetailsFocus(ChildDet)" ng-blur="OrderDetailsChange(parentDet.ID,$index,ChildDet)" ng-disabled="ChildDet.CheckStatus==true ?false:true" ng-model="ChildDet.OrderDetails" style="width:50px" class="ng-valid-min ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-max ng-valid-number">
     <label><button>Click to get value</button></label>
```